# Win 10 Wifi signal fluctutating

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Every time I shutdown and start my laptop, my WiFi only shows 1 out of 4 bars of signal strength.  But if I change roaming sensitivty in device manager to any other except which it already is. (Doesn't matter which I just need to switch it) then the signal gets back to 4 bars.

It is a HP-15 R003ne and used RT3920 bgn WiFi adpater. Have already updated drivers from HP's site.

I'm using windows 10. This problem started recently when I reset the laptop.

Comment: "This problem started recently when I reset the laptop" - This either means you are not using the same driver you were using.  Try using a previous version of the driver.  You might also just go ahead and replace the device, since it obviously is not fully compatible, with Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe the signal strength does not even drop. It could be that the grphics with signal strenth simply do not get updated.

Comment: May I ask how many AP's do you have deployed with the same SSID?

Comment: @pythonian I'm not sure what AP is. I don't think I've deployed any

Comment: @AFalseName - Sorry.  AP means Access Point or in your case Wireless Router